# Regex python extracting between two fields

Tags: python, regex

Hello I have a text file like such

```py
"text": "Tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 kararlara Deniz \u00c7oban yorumu Tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 kararlara Deniz \u00c7oban yorumu 19 Ocak 2021 21:14 beIN SPORTS yorumcusu Deniz \u00c7oban, S\u00fcper Lig 'de g\u00fcn\u00fcn kar\u015f\u0131la\u015fmalar\u0131nda ya\u015fanan tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 hakem pozisyonlar\u0131n\u0131 yorumlad\u0131. \u0130lgili Haberler", "country": "TR",
```

and I want to grab

```py
"Tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 kararlara Deniz \u00c7oban yorumu Tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 kararlara Deniz \u00c7oban yorumu 19 Ocak 2021 21:14 beIN SPORTS yorumcusu Deniz \u00c7oban, S\u00fcper Lig 'de g\u00fcn\u00fcn kar\u015f\u0131la\u015fmalar\u0131nda ya\u015fanan tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 hakem pozisyonlar\u0131n\u0131 yorumlad\u0131. \u0130lgili Haberler"
```

I have

```py
(?<="text": ")[^"]*
```

This pattern produces

```py
Tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 kararlara Deniz \u00c7oban yorumu Tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 kararlara Deniz \u00c7oban yorumu 19 Ocak 2021 21:14 beIN SPORTS yorumcusu Deniz \u00c7oban, S\u00fcper Lig 'de g\u00fcn\u00fcn kar\u015f\u0131la\u015fmalar\u0131nda ya\u015fanan tart\u0131\u015fmal\u0131 hakem pozisyonlar\u0131n\u0131 yorumlad\u0131. \u0130lgili Haberler
```

How should I change my regex pattern so that it includes the chat marks `"`...`"`?

Comment: Just add them to the consuming pattern, `(?<="text": )"[^"]*"`. However, since it is a JSON string, use `json` module to parse it.

Comment: well your exluding them by putting it in a not char capture. Just use something like this `"text":\s(".*?")`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sAEXIw/1 i tested the consuming pattern it definitely works however how should i adapt to find more matches

Comment: Well what kind of matches do you want? in the example you gave my regex captures what you expected

Comment: If you want to match all the key value pairs in the line then you can use `(".*?"):\s(".*?")` https://regex101.com/r/HFGBLP/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'"text":\s*("[^"]*")', s)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/hUIR6b/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "text":                  '"text":'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##vVhdd9u4EX33r5hqH@JsZYnUhx25p6fOOlY2rR0rsdtut2pzIBKksCFBLgB6bff0t6d3AMqRZJ3Ue3bbF4kGgcHMnTt3Rq7v3LLSw0@fVFlXxpGRe3tG5vKWfk/mWcfJW9c5ntuv9zt//2fnH193nj/b27N416G5fznvHOPpWhg3nzdRPIz91zgrRdEu0EdhhCnwQa@kVvfE61FyVC2EprvKNGVDv/R8PKHLRHykQTSIaRAfxyNayDdv6Wp2@f76KuxKGts8ttClK/9XltTS0LnK6VkqKW/X9OqbnWg9a90qxGdP23fDWKeC7lYvhIaD7kuRLcVHWVJd3St7V@k1M6sN3vFCpO3fPQoPUZGrQtG3YiFNIc2800UOkqrRzty1CXkfFguhw4JrzEdll2G1MUVYXTpX2@N@35neQiptmQK2l1Rlf8m2@@y9svBYHTxk4SBlDA8SRu8g4H8wGAbDqsw/WJNsGi9lqkQ06hUqdzdsvOdMHzv7Wv5k@5yyfoyvn3FZ/2j04sMoPvRHej/U@bzz7y79C4E1Kg2Xp4cii8fpIhoejcVkGI0Pk7FYDIdRFg/T8SSbDMZH0SgeB79Fgyow4WRYqZtFAbxka469PIjig3hyPRgeR@PjKOpFUfTbaICncOJzNVysch4NPH9Eqmm2thAfRkbe00ykZn11NAAbJXIotUgrQ6ksSP7YqLqiTJbAocASXQntKksHdCFvfb5oKopCJpKeeK3bXEq0Sqo1wzBJp9WNShErncGD222fTotmsdp9LvJGC5q2/jmpNz0QND4isX5jNMaxu1075S1KUEmdKDxrKrAPWQcABT/Cw1PT3NPL@6agb1UqiryCHWycNtLcC0vfbFwzsirB4gxOz3wuPVaMkbSsF7AntTQ@dM5ulwQVOBCPjscj@j@n8KIpHNKgnUj4DT9B7mxTG2m9Garx2h4H4RoAG/qxkaSRdqscvLZcrlSzSJawzpE5HDKVk7lKq/lcI5XtvamqECvuqBKckRYbywALvM08mVSJPDiPzf8UiUIQVMcp1yRq63TPky@cKJhlnKtC4Kjb3MlGysbH@3R3mTg3W1cCb6o3t1rc53kBXEpIrvBxpMpI5MnsLKUesPY3y@DAi8h/TZKnedZFYoE9ZUhvoyk36CEWaVo2yKsn/G0iC4AgkcGy3iotYNQlq/JmOzRXpcg81xFzokqqIlShEU6EXDPrDOhWVzrlBWl/B0uaZLkQJodZAXIozZ/eNUE3m9EkTpXIxFYR@jqzToCbOpUlEGTiCnz8IAgB2SrkVLL9jXBg0nIwmtnK/jM9y0Yzmx/Dm3bBpFQlW3G3lAegABOANUgR@Gh7UC6@VpSVp72V2qpFIR/zXzdwH9R7tUr69Y6kd@lkJpG9GlVQ6cMRMQvewjTuK8P9lRGPOO7FFqyTThrNt9lEaOsp9Co8eyWsBWixgz69dpBZgX2lZAnFYL5sZwHRf/UaRWK4in4Txog4DtBl4WsS8MxYanruJ@XglB8FvjdJfv23pXx5unHfUfKu2YQChZEBBS/gS3EXyp/evLvEBOa5dyNqyWog7R9WpuhMb1URKOkJshksILkW5UJt7tW0VIlCTD6/BagE86Fg62pR7EKcJdLIlN@y@GXcPHwtJE1ZF8qwMDLdIKrcDnh44WeWYCNvOLhtoYJrv0QkoSYq367XwRjoJQ0jWHmP2Jc2gcLziesZdNSyst3wN@oLZCq3LCVKo7/fKOauEr6iQDeUdS1Y8u8oHiI4A1UQlkM580mzjW3F1/qC3emklQ9OisfNuUvriLyIIUocxHspCunx/F4kcCFhny6NuhcLwTTBlqxt6ItdDf1z/wyzB/v8NKhb4fJVzWyENXwK3TBh01ClkAKFglaVF/rXjTCYXTX89b8suFy/0LJWfUr06M@ahTZjtUJmiqrtzcyr9W5ycon5PVcfrvzgjfD51mzd7Dhziwq6J28RvWbpgyeHTxSIJ3Kw9/P04C@Hcvbi/HYmLkOrG8AIvXScuenpwyi4f@KXpqftwnP6I6AWBoSbdAOc5xgcH9oqw3L@5vVLuvjuwUar0TQLULaNAhBNf80p5cxyG5R5aO4nPN4Ghk35x9lW8H/9LlHF5Dw9KmlN34PiYNTxxRJapng8OOzKLHPq1567vtir/ssM7@vJ8CgKmcQooXeI6ENUxisInnNuqe/OZq969NX0Yoqg3oa@Od0V8ham4z99Mx6fJdn9ZI1QUwlV2nH3RagET5ldxvdPcP8OsvkfAaVkPQWHgE/FWKcCP946e3u1UdrtG9nDiAP1Kvb9/0Agls@ff/r0Hw):

```py
import re

regex = r'"text":\s*("[^"]*")'

s = " \"text\": \"Tart\\u0131\\u015fmal\\u0131 kararlara Deniz \\u00c7oban yorumu Tart\\u0131\\u015fmal\\u0131 kararlara Deniz \\u00c7oban yorumu 19 Ocak 2021 21:14 beIN SPORTS yorumcusu Deniz \\u00c7oban, S\\u00fcper Lig 'de g\\u00fcn\\u00fcn kar\\u015f\\u0131la\\u015fmalar\\u0131nda ya\\u015fanan tart\\u0131\\u015fmal\\u0131 hakem pozisyonlar\\u0131n\\u0131 yorumlad\\u0131. \\u0130lgili Haberler\", \"country\": \"TR\", \"lan\": \"turkish\", \"url\": \"https://tr.beinsports.com/haber/tartismali-kararlara-deniz-coban-yorumu-23\", \"img_src\": \"https://media04.ligtv.com.tr/img/news/2021/1/20/tartismali-kararlara-deniz-coban-yorumu-23/748_416/tart.jpg\"}, {\"uuid\": \"d6af15db0375a93056c5ab330f13d59f92570415\", \"author\": \"\", \"published\": \"2021-01-19T23:05:00.000+02:00\", \"text\": \"Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n, entrenador del equipo femenil de Santos - Mexsport Fallece Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez t\\u0102\\u0160cnico de Santos por Covid-19 El ex entrenador del Club Santos Laguna Femenil ten\\u0102\\u00ada 57 a\\u0102\\u0105os y ten\\u0102\\u00ada experiencia en los banquillos de Cruz Azul Hidalgo y en Fuerzas B\\u0102\\u0104sicas Por Publisport Martes 19 de enero de 2021, a las 14:54 Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n, entrenador del equipo femenil de Santos - Mexsport Multicontactos contra supresor de picos:\\u00c2 lo que necesitas saber para mantenerte protegido\\nEl Santos dio a conocer este martes el fallecimiento de Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n, entrenador del equipo femenil de la instituci\\u0102\\u0142n. El equipo lagunero lament\\u0102\\u0142 la muerte de Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez y envi\\u0102\\u0142 su p\\u0102\\u0160same a la familia del director t\\u0102\\u0160cnico.\\n\\u00e2\\u0080\\u009cMart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez, quien fue un gran ser humano y excelente compa\\u0102\\u0105ero, sigui\\u0102\\u0142 todos los protocolos y tratamientos correspondientes; sin embargo, al final fue una v\\u0102\\u00adctima m\\u0102\\u0104s de esta pandemia que aqueja no solamente al pa\\u0102\\u00ads, sino a todo el mundo\\u00e2\\u0080\\u009d, indic\\u0102\\u0142 Santos en un comunicados. Lamentamos el sensible fallecimiento de nuestro Director T\\u0102\\u0160cnico, @Perezpadron64 .\\nNos unimos en oraci\\u0102\\u0142n por su eterno descanso.\\nDescansa en paz, Mart\\u0102\\u00adn. \\u00c2\\u0104Siempre ser\\u0102\\u0104s un #Guerrero ! \\u0111\\u009f\\u0099\\u008f pic.twitter.com/ZrcgTYheAC \\u00c2\\u017cQu\\u0102\\u0160 diferencia hay entre IQOS y los vapeadores? \\u00c2 Ent\\u0102\\u0160rate aqu\\u0102\\u00ad\\nTambi\\u0102\\u0160n hicieron un llamado a la poblaci\\u0102\\u0142n para redoblar esfuerzos y cumplir con todas las medidas de prevenci\\u0102\\u0142n.\\nMart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n, dirigi\\u0102\\u0142 25 encuentro con las Guerreras en dos torneos, en donde sum\\u0102\\u0142 cinco victorias, siete empates y 13 derrotas.\\nEntre sus equipos que dirigi\\u0102\\u0142 se encuentra Cruz Azul Hidalgo, \\u0102\\u0081guilas Reales de Zacatecas, Orizaba y las fuerzas b\\u0102\\u0104sicas de Santos Laguna.\\nP\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n fue uno de los casos anunciados en el inicio del Guardianes 2021 por la instituci\\u0102\\u0142n lagunera. Un profundo dolor para toda la familia @Orlegi_Sports y del f\\u0102\\u015ftbol mexicano\\u2026\\nDescansa en paz, Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n. \\u0111\\u009f\\u0099\\u008f pic.twitter.com/V6eP8LxPaO\\n\\u2014 Atlas FC Femenil (@AtlasFCFemenil) January 19, 2021 La Familia de la LIGA MX Femenil Lamenta Profundamente el Fallecimiento de Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n, Estratega del @ClubSantosFem pic.twitter.com/WXcil9Ld7m Nos unimos a la pena que embarga a la familia del f\\u0102\\u015ftbol por el fallecimiento de Mart\\u0102\\u00adn P\\u0102\\u0160rez Padr\\u0102\\u0142n, Director T\\u0102\\u0160cnico del Club Santos Laguna Femenil.\\nPronta resignaci\\u0102\\u0142n a familiares y amigos. QEPD. #FMFporNuestroF\\u0102\\u015ftbol pic.twitter.com/5KB55Ecfz9\\n\\u2014 Federaci\\u0102\\u0142n Mexicana de F\\u0102\\u015ftbol (@FMF) January 19, 2021 Publimetro te recomienda\","

print(re.findall(regex, s))
```